# ArrayList sobrescribe ultimo objeto ingresado C#

Tags: c#, lista, arraylist, objeto

**Saludos amigos**, necesito de su valiosa ayuda, ya que estoy intentado enviar información de 3 campos de texto de un formulario a otro, el método  button1_Click() del formulario 1 envía la información al método agregarTrabajador() del formulario 2 y este ultimo debe crear un objeto de tipo Persona y agregarlo a un ArrayList, el problema es que el método agrega el objeto pero al intentar agregar otro objeto lo que hace es sobre escribir el que había, ocasionando que solo haya un objeto en el ArrayList.

Nota: Es un trabajo para la universidad y solo debo usar ArrayList nada de Lista u otros, muchas gracias espero su **texto en negrita**pronta ayuda.

**Formulario 1.**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LamadoSegundaVentana
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            String nombre = textBox1.Text;
            int edad = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            int tel = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

            SegundoFormulario sf = new SegundoFormulario();
            sf.Show();
            sf.agregarTrabajador( nombre, edad, tel);
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

---

**Formulario 2**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LamadoSegundaVentana
{
    public partial class SegundoFormulario : Form
    {
        public SegundoFormulario()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int contador;
        String nombre;
        int edad;
        int tel;

        public String darNombre(String nombre)
        {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            return nombre;
        }
        public int darEdad(int pEdad)
        {
            this.edad = pEdad;
            return edad;
        }
        public int darTel(int tel)
        {
            this.tel = tel;
            return tel;
        }

        ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
        public ArrayList agregarTrabajador( String pNombre, int pEdad, int pTel)
        {
            lista.Add(new Trabajador(nombre, pEdad, pTel));
            contador = lista.Count;

            return lista;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Trabajador a in lista)
            {
                textBox1.Text += (a.darNombre() + ", " + a.darEdad() + ", " + a.dartelefono() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu enfoque está equivocado, siempre se guarda el último objeto ya que cada vez que construyes el form2, inicializas el ArrayList, cada vez que dices new Form2() ya es un nuevo ArrayList. Te propongo lo sgte , puedes sobrecargar el constructor del form2 y pasar a través de este los 3 parámetros que te hacen falta y además le pasarías un cuarto parámetro que sería el arraylist.

El arraylist lo inicializarias en el formulario1 y se lo pasarías como parámetro al formulario2

```
//Form1
ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();//sería una variable global para que sea visible a todo el form1


//Form2
public SegundoFormulario( string nombre, int edad, int tel, ArrayList lista)
{
   lista.Add(new Trabajador(nombre, edad, tel);
}
```

De esta forma ya el método agregar trabajador que tienes en form2 ya no te hace falta

En el form1 ahora llamarías al constructor pero esta vez al sobrecargado con 4 parámetros

```
//Form1
SegundoFormulario sf = new SegundoFormulario(pNombre, pEdad, pTel, pLista);
sf.Show();
```

Otra forma de hacerlo sería implementando un patrón singleton, si quieres puedes buscar más información en internet. Te soy sincero, solo tú sabrás lo que estás haciendo,pero yo realmente no le veo ningún sentido, creo que tienes un error de concepto, no obstante el código que te propongo funciona, úsalo, un saludo

Comment: amigo muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, lo voy a implementar y te cuento como me fue. La verdad es que estoy aprendiendo tal vez por eso este mal enfocada la solución, me darías una mano?. Como puedo capturar la información de un formulario y enviarlo a otro para crear un nuevo trabajador. te agradezco mucho si me explicaras cual es la manera optima de llevarlo a cabo.

Comment: ok te espero, espero te sirva